# Centering h1 in a div with background color

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble aligning my h1 tag in the center of my div. The div just displays a block of color and the h1 should fit in the center and right now its sitting at the top.

http://jsfiddle.net/ha632/

**HTML**

```
<div id='title' align="center">
    <h1>ExpressWay</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#title{
    background-color: #f5f82e;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6zew/ Code is fine

Comment: It is centered...do you want it centered vertically, also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [margins are collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). You can fix this by adding `overflow:auto` (or a border like `border:1px solid #f5f82e`) to your div:

```
#title{
    background-color: #f5f82e;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rMyTZ/6/)**

Comment: Don't know, gave you one back.

Comment: Thank you! My boss will be happy now.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this css:

```
#title{
    background-color: #f5f82e;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
```

You can play with padding value of #title.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `h1` a line-height or add padding to it.

A better solution would be to just remove the `div` altogether and apply your styles to the `h1` tag instead, unless you have a good reason for the `div`?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6zew/2/

Comment: Seems like some people here are just like to downvote everything they see :(

Comment: Yeah driveby downvoting, gotta love it.